# How to convert flat icon to simple 3d icon?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, inkscape, svg, icon

I'm trying to make a simple 3D icon from a flat SVG image, unfortunately without success.

What I want to achieve can be seen in the picture below.

[image: flat icon to 3d icon]

What steps should I take to get this effect? How do I get this perspective and 3D effect? I would be grateful for a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Start with Effect > 3D > Extrude and Bevel, play around with the settings, then Object > Expand the result to use as a base for your final product.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Illustrator's 3D Extrude and Bevel effect. Give the shape a thick coloured stroke and no fill, then apply *Effects > 3D > Extrude and Bevel*, and use similar settings as shown below. Tweak as necessary.

[image]

Here I added a white fill to the shape, and a second new light in the 3D Extrude and Bevel options.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Inkscape:

[image]

If you click once on your object, you get a bounding box to stretch it, but if you click twice, you get different arrows around the box for rotation and shearing, only one relevant of the 8 arrows shown. (Somehow the yellow circle was lost by copying the image over here.)

- By pulling the black arrow up/down you get the perspective effect (top right).
- Bottom left: duplicate.
- Bottom middle: path/difference of outer shape and circle. You save one step if you make the diff in the beginning, before shearing, but I thought the shearing might be your biggest problem.
- Bottom right:

  - Changed color,
  - added border around lighter background shape,
  - used a rotated rectangle for the white glance effect, to get a border for the floodfill tool.
  - Added an ellipse in the lower left corner. Joined it with the background object.

In the hole, there is the border of the background visible. Depending on your needs, this is left as a challenge for you, to get rid of.